# How orderer verifies the identities in case of multiple CAs

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, blockchain, hyperledger-fabric-ca

In Two Org setup in which each Org has its own CA for issuing certs, then how Orderering nodes identifies that particular request is coming from a known Org identity.

Answer (score 0):

It attempts to match the identity with each of the available MSP's and whichever had passed, verifies the identity to belong to that MSP.

This can be verified by looking at docker logs of orderer.

Comment: right, in the configtx.yaml  we define the MSPDir path, and configtxgen tool loads this info into the genesis block and if we want to add another org than it can add delta to genesis configuration but my query is the ( MSPDir:  ./PeerMSP) - Is this tag loads all the certs and even keys into the genesis block if not then what ?